# How to import two VueJS components inside eachother?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two components, an `item` component and a `folder` component. Each `item` contains it's own `folder` component, and each `folder` component contains a list of `item`s.

So I am trying to  use the `item` component in the `folder` component, and vice versa, however, I am getting the error: `unknown custom element: <item> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.` Despite the fact that I have the `name` option set on both components.
Any ideas?

Code is below

`item.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="item" style="height: 30px">
        . . .
        <folder v-if="item.hasChildren" :id="id"></folder>
    </div>
</template>


<script scoped>
import Folder from './folder.vue';

export default {
    name: 'item',
    props: ['id'],
    components: {
        Folder
    }
};

</script>
```

`folder.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="folder">
        <template v-for="(child, index) in children">
            <item :last-item="index === children.length - 1" :key="child.id" :id="child.id"></item>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Item from "./item.vue";

export default {
    name: 'folder',
    props: ['id', 'hasChildren'],
    components: {
        Item
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably happening because of the [circular referencing](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components) between your components ..

> When you look closely, you’ll see that these components will actually
> be each other’s descendent and ancestor in the render tree - a
> paradox!

To resolve this paradox you can either register your components globally using `Vue.component`, or you can defer the import of one of your components to a later point (by moving your import to the `beforeCreate` hook or using [async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components) as demonstrated [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components)) ..

`folder.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="folder">
        <template v-for="(child, index) in children">
            <item :last-item="index === children.length - 1" :key="child.id" :id="child.id"></item>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'folder',
    props: ['id', 'hasChildren'],
    components: {
        'item': () => import('./item.vue')
    }
};

</script>
```

Comment: Why should OP use async components?

Comment: @Phil I'll defer to you on this but in the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components) they present it as a solution to circular referencing between components.

Comment: That's a great piece of information that should be mentioned in your answer. It gives people a reason to visit the links you provide

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the key (name) in the components object like so,

item.vue

```
components: {
    folder: Folder
}
```

folder.vue

```
components: {
    item: Item
}
```

Comment: That or use `<Folder>` and `<Item>`